Missing page views in Realtime report
In our site the page_view events displayed in realtime report have completely collapsed whereas the user_engagement events remain high.
E.g. currently 2430 user_engagement events are shown and only 6 page_view events which makes absolutely no sense (with a current user count of 900).
When debugging the site using tagassistant, everything works fine. Page views are sent (same as user engagement) and no errors are shown.
I tried setting send_page_view to true in gtag config like the following:
<script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());
      gtag('config', 'G-12345ABCDE', { send_page_view: true });
</script>

But with no success.
Any ideas how to investigate further?


There's a few things that can cause this, so I don't think anyone can give you a definitive answer. Examples include: CMP interfering with the page_view trigger, using an SPA, or misconfiguration of your GA4 property.

Finally it was all about cookie consent configuration.
The page_view event was passed to GA with a gcs (gcs = consent mode) value of G100 (restricted consent) whereas the user_engagement was passed to GA with gcs value G111 (full consent).
One can nicely observe this by using Tag Assistant.
After moving the consent script in the HTML head to an upper position, the page_view event was passed also with a G111 value and the issue has been fixed.
